# how to get surrogate variables in rpart

Tags: variables, rpart

I have looked everywhere I can, but I couldn't find answer to my question regarding rpart package.

I have built a regression tree using rpart, I have around 700 variables. I want to get the variables actually used to build the tree including the surrogates. I can find the actual variables used using tree$variable.importance, but I also have to get the surrogates because I need them to predict on the test set data I have. I do not want to keep all the 700 variables in the test set as I have a very big data (20mil observations) and I am running out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

The list `variable.importance` in an rpart object does show the surrogate variables, but it only shows the top variables limited by a minimum importance value.

The matrix `splits` in an rpart object lists all of the split variables and their surrogate variables along with some other data like `index`, the value on which it splits (for continuous variable) or the categories that are split (for categorical variable), `count` how many observations are that split applies to. It doesn't give a hierarchy of which surrogates apply to which split, but it does list every variable. To get the hierarchy, you have to do `summary(rpart_object)`.